# GDAL Script Failing since GDA2020 Shift - unable to find EPSG 7855

Tags: gdal, ogr, gda2020

I have a series of ogr2ogr scripts that run daily on our Intramaps server. Since shifting our GIS data to GDA2020 I notice these scripts fail with
`ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 7855 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid EPSG coordinate system?`

I tested removing any reference of SRID within the scripts and rebooted the server that it runs on in case of any weird glitch. We use GDAL for our corporate GIS Intramaps so I use the server to run my GDAL scripts for various GIS file conversions. This particular script converts SQL to kml and has always worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a try with GDAL 3.6.0dev from gisinternals.com and with GDAL 3.4.1 from  OSGeo4W. Both can deal with EPSG:7855. What is your GDAL version? What do you get with this gdalsrsinfo command?

```
gdalsrsinfo epsg:7855

PROJ.4 : +proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

OGC WKT2:2018 :
PROJCRS["GDA2020 / MGA zone 55",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GDA2020",
        DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 2020",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",7844]],
    CONVERSION["Map Grid of Australia zone 55",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",147,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Engineering survey, topographic mapping."],
        AREA["Australia - onshore and offshore between 144┬░E and 150┬░E."],
        BBOX[-50.89,144,-9.23,150.01]],
    ID["EPSG",7855]]
```

Comment: PROJ.4 : +proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["GDA2020 / MGA zone 55",
    GEOGCS["GDA2020",
        DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_2020",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","1168"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","7844"]],

Comment: PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",147],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","7855"]]

Comment: Sorry, I had to reply in two sections due to the length of the results. As GDAL is installed as part of Intramaps I am unsure of the version but I see a heap of csv files containing EPSG codes, such as compdcs.csv, coordinate_axis.csv, datum_shift.csv etc. If you have 7855 in one of these files would it work if I added it to the same file our end?

Comment: You can check the GDAL version with `gdalinfo --version`.

Comment: Looks like a very old very version. GDAL 2.1.4, released 2017/06/23.

Comment: It even throws the same error if my script uses 28355. Could it be reading the source EPSG from the SQL feature class being used to convert? I couldn't find 7855 in the various GDAL files.

Comment: I suggest to have a try with a current GDAL version which is 3.5.2 by now.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the environment path variables were pointing to the Miniconda GDAL folder, not the Intramaps one. I updated it and it works. Not sure when or how this changed but it works now thanks.